# Making 2 textbox fields to dynamic in size

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have 2 textbox fields. I would like to make them dynamic - as soon as the values ​​in the upper field slide down, I want the lower field to slide down automatically.

I used the CAN GROW option for both fields and the text still overlaps each other..are there any other parameters I should set?

THIS IS THE RESULT THAT I'M GETTING :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When fields are placed within a section of a report in CR, their position is relative to the top left corner of the section.  So if one field can grow within the section, the other fields in that same section do not adjust or move around the text field when it grows in size because the top left corner of the section has not moved.

To solve this, duplicate the section where the text field that can grow is placed.  Fields that need to be pushed down the page when the text field grows should be placed in the duplicated section.  The original section will grow as needed with the text field, and the new section below it will be pushed down the page as the section above grows.  And since the fields in the new section are anchored to the top left corner of the new section, they will be pushed down the page with the new section.